# Excel column containing unique ID number

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create an excel spreadsheet that will contain a unique number (ID) that's automatically assigned to each row.

| Unique ID | Some text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |
| 3 | ghi |
| 4 | jkl |

Is it possible to get the following result when a new row is inserted between existing rows (in this example: between entry 2 and 3)? The existing IDs should not be changed, and a new ID should be assigned to the new row.

| Unique ID | Some text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |
| 5 | this is the new row |
| 3 | ghi |
| 4 | jkl |

Are macros the best way to do this?
As far as I know, if formulas are used then they will not be automatically copied a newly inserted row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is certainly not perfect, but it's a good start:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 2 Then
  Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1
  End If
End Sub
```

It means that:

- If you change something in your sheet
  `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`
- If you change it in the second column ("B")
  `If Target.Column = 2 Then`
- Take the cell in the first column (the one to the left)
  `Target.Offset(0, -1)`
- Put there the maximum value of the entire "A" column plus one:
  `WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1`

This is the way to add this:

[image]